# Driver class not found: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver

Tags: firebird, jaybird

I have problem with update from firebird 2.1 to 2.5. If I do it, system respond me this:

> Unable to connect to database. Driver class not found: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver

Is it problem of PATH ?

```
update_database:
     [echo] Updating database module: support
[updateDatabase] May 16, 2017 9:14:34 AM org.dbmaintain.datasource.SimpleDataSource createDataSource
[updateDatabase] INFO: Creating data source. Driver: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver, url: jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3054:d:/firebird/sh_test/SH.FDB, user: sysdba, password: <not shown>

BUILD FAILED
d:\migrace\9352\build.xml:307: The following error occurred while executing this line:
d:\migrace\9352\data\build.xml:159: Unable to perform db maintain task.
**Unable to connect to database. Driver class not found: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver**
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
```

Comment: You might want to include the relevant parts of your ant script

Answer (score 2):

This error has nothing to do with Firebird itself, nor the update from Firebird 2.1 to 2.5. This error means that you don't have Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver) on the class path of whatever you are executing.

Add Jaybird to the class path and this error should go away.